# Error in lm.fit(x, y, offset = offset, singular.ok = singular.ok, ...) : 0 (non-NA) cases

Tags: r, lm

When I did

```
reg <- lm(X4 ~., data = donnees.train)
```

Why did I see this error?

```
# Error in lm.fit(x, y, offset = offset, singular.ok = singular.ok, ...) : 
#  0 (non-NA) cases
```

My `csv` file has 12 column `X1`,`X2`,....,`X12` numeric values for input and one column `Y1` for output.

Comment: Please include output of `head(donnees.train)`. It seems you have a column filled with `NA` values.

Comment: My Output column :
Y1
400
840
17180
181
434
708
15540
122
448
1020
11530
508
453
756
7800
411
571
513
1313
379
761
655
8590
480

Comment: I am skeptical that this is the output of `head(donnees.train)`. The `lm` function is expecting `donnees.train` to include one element named `X4`, and at least one other element. Here you've just given me your `Y1` vector. Run `head(donnees.train)` and then edit your post and paste in the output.

Comment: I run the code you told ;
head(donnees.train)
[1] X2 X3 X4
<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)

Sorry my English is not good and my answers may not be correct to you.

Comment: `0 rows` indicates that `donnees.train` contains no data. You've made a mistake somewhere with your subsetting and are trying to fit a model without any data.

Comment: So the problem is with my csv file?

Comment: Perhaps, but based on your [other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21959690/how-can-i-change-my-r-code-to-run-my-new-csv-file-data#comment33273245_21959690), I think it's more likely that you've done something wrong when you subset `donnees` to create `donnees.train`. Read the information at `?'['`.